# Injecting JSON-LD (Schema) scripts into head of WordPress site

Tags: javascript, wordpress, schema, json-ld, structured-data

I have a bunch of JSON-LD files that I want to inject into the head of various pages, some conditionally. I'm using WordPress, and their recommendation is to use a function like `wp_enqueue_script`. The difficulty is I've yet to find a way to edit the `<type>` attribute using the `wp_enqueue_script` function.

I was able to do it clumsily with PHP like this (maybe there's a better PHP function?):

```
// header.php

<head>
    ...all the regular stuff..

    ..near the bottom..
    <?php
        if ( is_front_page() ) {
            echo file_get_contents(get_template_directory() . '/assets/structured-data/local-business.js');
        } 
    ?>

</head>
```

The scripts I'm trying to inject are formatted like this:

```
// JSON-LD format
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
    "@context": "http://schema.org",
    "@type": "localBusiness",
    "currenciesAccepted": ...
}
</script>
```

So I`m just trying to read the files in. This breaks when I try to include multiple scripts.

I would like to follow WP recommendations and use a method like `wp_enqueue_script()` but as of yet, I haven't found a way to do that. The whole function won't work unless I can mark the scripts as `type="application/ld+json"`, required for JSON-LD.

Comment: I've decided to just hard-code them into the header.php file for now. There's also development on a [new core WP function](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/22249) to alter `attr` values on script/style tag generation hopefully coming soon.

Answer (score 4):

The way I am currently doing this is with add_action();

```
add_action( 'wp_head', 'my_theme_schema' );
```

Then in my_theme_schema, I build my schema, and just output it with the script tags.  ( I typically build the schema with an array ).

```
function my_theme_schema() {
  $schema = [];
  ... // build up the schema
  $output = json_encode( $schema, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES );
  ?>
    <script type="application/ld+json">
      <?= $output; ?>
    </script>
  <?php
}
```

This gives me the opportunity to put it in the functions.php.

Also, I typically do not put it in the head, I put it in the footer.

```
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'my_theme_schema' );
```

I don't know if one is inherently better, I just prefer JS in the footer.

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to do this:

```
//here we enqueue a dummy script to help us with what we want to achieve
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'myslug_wp_load_files');
function myslug_wp_load_files()
{
    wp_register_script( 'myslug-dummy-handle-json-footer', plugins_url('scripts/loader.js', __FILE__), [], '', true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'myslug-dummy-handle-json-footer'  );
}

//here we construct our ldjson and add it to our enqueued script
add_action('wp_head', 'myslug_construct_ldjson');
function myslug_construct_ldjson()
{
    $my_ldjson = '{construct_here_your_ldjson}';
    wp_add_inline_script( 'myslug-dummy-handle-json-footer', $my_ldjson );
}

//here we add a filter to the script loader, and modify text/javascript to application/ld+json
add_filter( 'script_loader_tag', 'myslug_async_tag', 10, 3 );

function myslug_async_tag( $tag, $handle, $src ) 
{
    if ( $handle !== 'myslug-dummy-handle-json-footer' ) 
    {
        return $tag;
    }
    $tag = str_replace("type='text/javascript'", "type='application/ld+json'", $tag);
    return $tag;
}
```

The above script registers and enqueue a dummy script - which can be practically anything (or even blank). Also, it adds the dynamically generated JSON-LD to the dummy script and then it filters all scripts, selects only the script we created and replaces type 'text/javascript' with type 'application/ld+json'.